# Why trying to enable NULL values in a MySQL timestamp field fails?

Tags: mysql-5.7, import, alter-table

I imported the table `delete_me` from the following `mysqldump`'s exported file

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.42, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: 192.168.00.00    Database: main
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.6.14-1+debphp.org~precise+1

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `delete_me`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `delete_me`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;

CREATE TABLE `delete_me` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `arrival` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
```

When I try to modify the `arrival` column the execution of the command fails. The error message seems irrelevant to me because it mentions another column - `created`.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE delete_me MODIFY arrival TIMESTAMP NULL;
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'created'
```

Anyways, the declaration of `arrival` column stays unchanged.

```
mysql> DESCRIBE delete_me;
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field   | Type                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| ID      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| arrival | timestamp           | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| created | datetime            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I create the table manually the alteration of the column get executed without an error. Therefore it looks like any of `SET` instructions in the exported file prevents the alteration of the column. I mean those instructions enclosed by `/*! */`.

I want to make `arrival` collumn nullable. Any ideas why exactly my tries to do it fail and how to go around that error? Am I doing something wrong?

```
mysql> SELECT version();
+-------------------------+
| version()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.42-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: This is [Server SQL Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html)-dependent, precisely `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_DATE`. Investigate `SELECT @@sql_mode;`. See https://dbfiddle.uk/4dOi-Nv5

Comment: @Akina `SELECT @@sql_mode;` returns `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`. Should I remove - `NO_ZERO_IN_DATA` and `NO_ZERO_DATE`?

Comment: I was allowed to alter the field after I've executed `SET sql_mode = 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';` and restored the original value of `sql_mode` after. I'll try your proposal later.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/W_631-ni

Comment: @Akina I get it now and it works. Thanks, you can write down your answer in another post so I can mark it as accepted, if you please.

Comment: I think it would be better if you write a detailed self-answer and accept it. Firstly, you will be able to tell exactly how each separate setting affects the result, and secondly, you will better understand this topic yourself.